# Mutating a matrix such that only list gets changed instead of the whole matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm trying to make blackjack in python. Say I have a matrix representing the cards which are present in the game. Say: [[3,9][2,7][1,5]]. If someone would call a command asking for a extra card i would like to add one card to someone's list. Is there a command to add one number to a list without re-writing the whole matrix? So let's say I wan't my array to look like this [[3,9,1][2,7][1,5]]. I've tried numpy append and insert but they give an error saying it is out of bounds.

Thanks for the response in advance.

Kind regards,
Jordi

Comment: Numpy can't do that. Why don't you just do something like `l[0].append(value)`, where `l` is the list you have?

Comment: ````
array = [[3,9],[2,7],[1,5]]
newarr = array[0].append(int(3))
print(newarr)
````
If i try to print this it outputs None

Comment: Because `append` is an inplace operation. It returns `None` and appends the new value in the array. Just `array[0].append(3)` and try to `print(array)` afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a numpy array you have to pay attention to the dimension, otherwise you should reshape the array.
You can try this simple solution with lists:

```
    your_list = [[3, 9],[2, 7],[1, 5]]
    your_list[0].append(1)
```